# Using command line input in java

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I'm trying to read input from the command line in main and then open that file in the public void part of my code. How can I do this in my code?

```
package dev;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import lotus.domino.*;
public class platform1 extends NotesThread implements Comparable <platform1>
{
  public static void main(String[] argv)
  {
    platform1 t = new platform1();
    t.start();
  }
  public void runNotes() 
  {
   try
   {
    Collection NotesDates = new ArrayList();
    Session s = NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess();
    Database db = s.getDatabase("" , (I want to open argv[0] here));
```

Comment: Using your favourite search enginge on the terms "java" and "command line arguments" or "argv" should give you some good results.

Comment: I guess he wants to get that value inside another Thread, still... Just get that value on your `main` method and pass it to the Thread.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that I already tried to figure this out by searching! The examples I found were mostly conceptual and did not relate to the way I was trying to use the input.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointing me to passing the variables, what I was looking for was how I could do that. I found that this works:

```
package dev;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import lotus.domino.*;
public class platform1 extends NotesThread implements Comparable <platform1>
{

    private String nsfarg;

    public static void main(String[] argv)
  {
    platform1 t = new platform1(argv);
    t.start();
  }
    private platform1(String[] argv){
        this.nsfarg = argv[0];
    }
  public void runNotes() 
  {
   try
   {
    Collection NotesDates = new ArrayList();
    Session s = NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess();
    Database db = s.getDatabase("" , (this.nsfarg.toString()));
```